# How to set Azure IOT Hub "System properties"?

Tags: json, azure, azure-blob-storage, mqtt, iot

Azure isn't appending the system properties onto my messages.  This creates problems when I try to route my message to the blob storage.

I need to add these:

```
"contentType":"application/json",
"contentEncoding":"utf-8",
```

In the test/properties, I can see the settings are correct, but is this for testing only or message routing?  Thoughts on this?

Comment: No this is not only for testing purpose.

We can set encoding format only when configuring the blob storage endpoint. After that we cannot change the format of encoding once its configured earlier.

For changing the encoding formats for an existing endpoint, delete the endpoint first and again create it with the format we need.

Refer this to know more about [azure storage as routing endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c#azure-storage-as-a-routing-endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the properties when instantiating the Message:

```
var messageToSend = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData))
{
    ContentType = "application/json",
    ContentEncoding = "utf-8"
};
```

The complete example to send the message:

```
async Task SendToIoTHub(OdtcDataEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var sensorValues = eventArgs.GetSensorValues();
    string jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(sensorValues);
    var messageToSend = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData))
    {
        ContentType = "application/json",
        ContentEncoding = "utf-8"
    };

    if (_deviceClient != null)
    {
        await _deviceClient.SendEventAsync(messageToSend).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).